# Custom xsd file to C# classes deserialization on runtime

Tags: asp.net, xsd, xsd.exe

I am trying to convert xsd file to the .net class.
I have searched a lot for this topic and found xsd.exe as one of the way to achieve it, but I still have two concerns

1. I don't want to manually generate the classes from command prompt but want all this to get done on runtime. For that I tried to use System.Diagnostics.Process to run xsd.exe on runtime but could not get succeeded and also was getting a blinking command prompt window when process starts.
2. I even didn't get succeeded to get the classes generated from command prompt also. It is giving me error "Schema D:\Response.xsd could not be validated."

So basically I am trying to implement something that will use my xsd string and deserialize it to one of my class' type on runtime, something like we do with Xml string using XmlSerializer class.

I would like to mention that I think my xsd string is not of the general xsd types but kind of custom, an example of one of the responses is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service"
xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common"
xmlns:use="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user">
    <serv:header>
        <serv:response>
            <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
            <serv:gsbStatus>BACKUP</serv:gsbStatus>
        </serv:response>
    </serv:header>
    <serv:body>
        <serv:bodyContent xsi:type="use:getLoginTicketResponse"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <use:ticket>5e9733eb9efeb02d80aa0551ef7e9ccd</use:ticket>
            <use:apiVersion>WebEx XML API V3.9.0</use:apiVersion>
        </serv:bodyContent>
    </serv:body>
</serv:message>
```

**Edit** -
 I got succeeded in generating the class file for my xml now and here it is

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user")]
public partial class getLoginTicketResponse : bodyContentType
{

    private string ticketField;

    private string apiVersionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ticket
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ticketField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ticketField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string apiVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return this.apiVersionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.apiVersionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is bodyContentType

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(getLoginTicketResponse))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("getLoginTicket", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class bodyContentType
{
}
```

Now, trying to serialize it like this

```
var nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(responseXML.NameTable);
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("serv", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service");
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("com", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common");
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("meet", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/meeting");
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("att", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/attendee");
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("use", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user");

XmlNode statusNode = responseXML.SelectSingleNode("/serv:message/serv:body", nameSpaceManager);
TextReader reader = new StringReader(s);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(getLoginTicketResponse));

var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

But keep on getting the error 
"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)." 
I tried changing many things in the xml string, but could not get succeeded

Any help will be appreciable!

Comment: this is not an XSD, this just on xml response.

Comment: @rene Oops! ok. So can you please give me an example of how can I design a class for this structure. I am not getting what should be the class name, what should be the property name etc. for this structure. Thanks!

Comment: I would assume you have got an wsdl for the endpoint the response is coming from? That would make life easier.

Comment: I have just tried something with xsd.exe. I used my passed my xml to it to generate xsd file for it and it generated it correctly, then I am trying to generate class from that xsd file. I think it is parsing it now properly but getting a different error now, "The element 'http://webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user:ticket' is missing."

Comment: Inferring the XSD from an instance of an xml is not always going to give you the exact XSD you are looking for. You want the one defined as part of the endpoint contract (published as part of the WSDL).

Comment: I have made progress to generate class for my xml but stuck in deserialization process. I have edited the question to post my progress code

Comment: Hello! how to generate classes?, im gave me a error, passing xsd files to cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a very decent and easy approach to deserialize my xml using XDocument!!!! :) :)

Here is how I am doing it now

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
XNamespace userNS = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user";
XNamespace servNS = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service";
var re = from rssItem in xDoc.Descendants(servNS + "bodyContent")
                 let elementTicket = rssItem.Element(userNS + "ticket")
                 let elementApiVersion = rssItem.Element(userNS + "apiVersion")
                 where (elementTicket != null && elementApiVersion != null)
                 select new getLoginTicketResponse()
                 {
                     ticket = elementTicket.Value,
                     apiVersion = elementApiVersion.Value
                 };

getLoginTicketResponse loginTicketResponse = re.First();
```

And I get my class object deserialized from the xml directly, **no XSD nothing is required**!

Let me show you my xml here again

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service"
xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common"
xmlns:use="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user">
    <serv:header>
        <serv:response>
            <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
            <serv:gsbStatus>BACKUP</serv:gsbStatus>
        </serv:response>
    </serv:header>
    <serv:body>
        <serv:bodyContent xsi:type="use:getLoginTicketResponse"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <use:ticket>5e9733eb9efeb02d80aa0551ef7e9ccd</use:ticket>
            <use:apiVersion>WebEx XML API V3.9.0</use:apiVersion>
        </serv:bodyContent>
    </serv:body>
</serv:message>
```